# VTK Python change camera's mouse controls to trackball (à la Blender, Meshlab, CloudCompare)

Tags: python, user-interface, mouse, vtk

If you look at the Python examples provided on [VTK's wiki](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python) you'll see that most (all?) viewers have mouse controls that may feel strange. For instance in the  [Cylinder](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/Cylinder) Hello world the object moves in a direction that depends of where you click in the window (regardless of where the object is). The rotation function similarly at a speed proportional to the distance from the window's center.

Is it possible to change the camera control style to "trackball" ? i.e. to something closer to the behavior of Blender, Meshlab or CloudCompare...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me quite a while to find the solution:

```
renderWindowInteractor.GetInteractorStyle().SetCurrentStyleToTrackballCamera()
```

where `renderWindowInteractor` was returned by `vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()` (sometimes called `iren` in the examples).

Comment: To do that in C++, see [this_exemple](https://web.archive.org/web/20200407105930/https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Interaction/TrackballCamera/)